# Delphi 2009 ShellTreeView/ShellListView Fix

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

When a Delphi 2009 project is closed with ShellTreeView/ShellListView on the mainform in the IDE Index out of bounds(0) exceptions are generated.  Is there a fix for ShellTreeView/ShellListView so the exceptions can be eliminated?

Answer (score 3):

That's the first I've heard of this. If it's any consolation I can reproduce it here.

The first thing you should do is probably file a bug report in [Quality Central](http://qc.codegear.com), and ask on the Codegear NNTP Newsgroups.

Also, try changing TCustomShellListView.GetFolder to the code below, and see how you get on. You'll need to rebuild the package - and beware that for some reason D2009 installs a second copy of this package in Windows\System32. I renamed that with (so far) no ill effects.

```
function TCustomShellListView.GetFolder(Index: Integer): TShellFolder;
begin
  if Index < FFolders.Count then
    Result := TShellFolder(FFolders[Index])
  else
    Result := NIL;
end;
```

Comment: I strongly agree - this should be posted in QC, then others can up-vote it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ TCustomShellTreeView }
...
  TCustomShellTreeView = class(TCustomTreeView, IShellCommandVerb)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override; //$$jp shellctrl.pas 26.08.2007: missing "override"
    procedure Refresh(Node: TTreeNode);
...

destructor TCustomShellTreeView.Destroy;
begin
  //$$jp: ClearItems;
  //$$jp: raises EInvalidOperation and access-violations (shellctrl.pas 26.08.2007)
  FRootFolder.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing suggested so far works to fix the problem...  but if I remove the ShellListView component from a demo project and then close the project no exception is created.  I think the problem is with the ShellListView component not the ShellTreeView.

The problem may be larger than it appears.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs **only** at design time.

Here' s a solution for the `TShellListView` component to apply on `ShellCtrls.pas` file:

```
destructor TCustomShellListView.Destroy;
begin
  ClearItems;
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then // Avoid design time error
  FFolders.Free;
  FreeAndNil(FRootFolder);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCustomShellListView.DestroyWnd;
begin
  ClearItems;

  // Avoid error in inherited DestroyWnd procedure :
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
  Items.Count := 0;
  inherited DestroyWnd;
end;
```